# How to set dynamic price to products in catalog listing (category) page?

Tags: catalog, price, event-observer, category

I am currently working on a site, where all the **product price are in terms of Reward points**, i.e customers can redeem their credit card reward points in this website.

So the product price should be dynamic according to the card type selected by the customer in the home page. For **example**, a customer visit the site

1. There is a popup asking him/her to select the type of card they are going to use for this transaction.
2. They select their credit card type viz. platinum, gold or diamond.
3. This is stored in my module's session.
4. The price of the product is displayed as 5000 points for platinum card, 6500 points for diamond card and 8000 points for gold card.

Now I use `catalog_product_get_final_price` event, so when the customer goes to the product view page, the price is set to the calculated price (points).

Here's my code

**config.xml**:

```
<events>
    <catalog_product_get_final_price>
            <observers>
                <price_change_for_card>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>price/observer</class>
                    <method>getCardAndModifyViewPrice</method>
                </price_change_for_card>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_get_final_price>
```

**Observer.php**:

```
class Royal_Price_Model_Observer{

public function getCardAndModifyViewPrice($observer){
        /*
          calculations for my dynamic price based on selected card type
        */
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->setFinalPrice($dynamic_price);
}
...
```

This **works perfectly fine right from product view page** until checkout. **But category page (listing page) still displays the price given in the admin panel**.

**How can I display the dynamic price right from the category page?**

> note:
>
> the price given in the admin panel is vital as it is the base price
>   for calculating dynamic price according to the card type.

Comment: The `get_final_price` event is not dispatched in the product list (as you found out by now). You can try one of the suggestions posted by the Magento team here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=10777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Magento Team,

- The **product page** product is loaded on its own so `catalog_product_get_final_price` event is triggered.
- **List page** uses the prices from the **catalog_product_index_price** table and doesn't trigger the above mentioned event.

So I've overriden `getFinalPrice` method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class to set the final price with the custom value calculated by my logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here follow a piece of code

```
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){ // you can remove the DI if you want to
        // Get the quote item
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        // Load the custom price you can change to any variable you want
        $price = (int)Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('custom_price');
        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
```

I charged a lot for it down here in brazil make good use of it.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to this question..